# Returning AJAX messages into a modal window via Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog

This is a nice little ajax upload snippet that will return messages via ajax on a successful upload or file too large...that sort of thing. In the upload.php Iis where I have the divs that contain the messages that are returned to the form page. I was wondering how I might modify this so that the divs/messages are returned into a modal window instead of just returning into the page itself...hopefully someone can help me out. Do I need to use jquery ui somewhere? Thanks, guys!

```
     $j(document).ready(function(){
var upload = new AjaxUpload('#userfile', {
        //upload script 
        action: '/modules/mod_artuploader/upload.php',
        onSubmit : function(file, extension){
        //show loading animation
        //$j("#loading").show();
        //check file extension
        if (! (extension && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(extension))){
       // extension is not allowed
             $j("#loading").hide();
             $j("<span class='error'>Error: Not a valid file extension</span>").appendTo("#file_holder #errormes");
            // cancel upload
       return false;
            } else {
              // get rid of error
            $j('.error').hide();
            }   
            //send the data
            upload.setData({'file': file, 'userid': <?php echo $user->id?> });
        },
        onComplete : function(file, response){
        //hide the loading animation
        $j("#loading").hide();
        $j("#userfile").hide();
        $j('label[for="userfile"]').hide();
        //add display:block to success message holder
        $j(".success").css("display", "block");
        $j(".picture").css("display", "block");
        //This lower portion gets the error message from upload.php file and appends it to our specifed error message block
        //find the div in the iFrame and append to error message    
        var oBody = $j(".iframe").contents().find("div");
        //add the iFrame to the errormes td
        $j(oBody).appendTo("#file_holder #errormes");

}
    });
}); 
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you use for a modal. If you're talking about a separate browser window, floating undocked or in a new tab, that's a very complicated problem to solve. Since you brought it up, jQuery UI dialog is an excellent choice. Take a look at the [modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) example. User could click an 'upload' button that activates the modal popup with the file selector. You can toggle display of a dialog with `$(foo).dialog('open')` and `$(foo).dialog('close')`. Then upload script can just live in the dialog and interact with elements in there. At least, I think your callback will be able to call into the dialog with an appendTo. What you may end up having to do is open one dialog for the upload, wait for a response, then close it and open another with the results.